# How to disable the categories sidebar in the product detail page in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, sidebar, product-detail-page, product-view-page, enable-disable

Is there an option in the admin area of Magento 2, to disable the sidebar on the left with the list of categories in the product detail page of the frontstore?

Comment: yes it is possible but which theme you are using and which block you have called on both pages

Answer (score 0):

Using out of the box magento, I believe  this is only possible by removing that block on the product page xml file. If you have a third party theme, I’d check with their documentation